# How to bootstrap Firefox Sync on many machines?

Tags: configuration, firefox, synchronization

Is it possible to **automate the configuration of Firefox Sync** on a bunch of machines? I've tried copying `profiles.ini` and the `services.sync.*` settings from `~/.mozilla/firefox/*/prefs.js` to `user.js`, but that's not enough - Firefox doesn't recognize this as a working configuration. I don't want to copy *all* the configuration files over, because that would stamp over various settings which should *not* be synced, such as passwords and browser history. Also, I'm worried that copying any settings containing GUIDs will break the sync functionality in subtle ways.